# What default dll's are imported into an asp.net webforms project

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms

I've inherited a legacy code base that doesn't currently compile and has no project or solution file (there are multiple repositories including winforms and asp.net).

I'm not certain what .net version the original code was written in, nor what the project template was, although I know some are web forms.

I'm re-creating new solution and project files to import the code into, but need to find some of the default dll's included in old Visual Studio project templates (e.g. webforms).

Any ideas where I might find this information?

Anyone know an MSDN link with this on it?

P.S. I don't have access to the production code, although it is running in production.

Comment: Will, please remove asp-classic tag, your question is about asp.net. If you don't have the project files, how did you get the source files (any source control)?

Comment: It's a buyout, we have bought a limited subset of another companies codebase and that doesn't include access to their repositories, so the history is non-existent from my point of view.